# Why i can't get a dependency on the Google Play Services library?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

I know that it has been asked hunderds of times, but I really can't find a solution for my issue.

I have this build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gelasoft.gatanki"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:0.0.+'
}
```

Às you can see I'm trying to compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:0.0.+`

But I;m getting some scary errors that I really can not manage. I have updated everything and the issue is still there.

Here the errors are:

When I'm trying to sync the project with gradle it says:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:0.0.+
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

and in my manifest where I'm trying this it can not be resolved as well:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I know that I'm missing a really small part on it, but I really can not figure out what is wrong.

Can you give me a push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there never was a 0.0.x version of the Play Services SDK. Try perhaps `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'` or `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'`.